# Freelancer working on shopping cart with access to Paypal API Credentials

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I've hired a freelancer thru freelancer.com and I need my shopping cart fixed so it will take paypal, I've already setup the API credentials in woocommerce on my wordpress site.

When the freelancer is done, should I change credentials or change my PayPal password and what kind of access can this freelancer have to my accounts in PayPal?

What other security steps should I take to ensure there is less security concerns after this work is done?

Comment: what kind of access you have given to your developer. Have you shared paypal credidentails too ?

Comment: They have access to my wordpress site which has the API credentials entered into the woocommerce plugin

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to worry about those credentials because that API is only for receiving funds. But save side if you want peace of mind you can change credentials from paypal.
Cheers!